# How do I remove ttk.Combobox borderline?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

test_value=['all', 'multi', 'one']

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("test Example")
root.geometry("500x200")

frm = tk.Frame(root)
frm.configure(width=500, height=500)
frm.place(x=0, y=0)

test_lbl = tk.LabelFrame(frm, text="import")
test_lbl.configure(width=350, height=30)
test_lbl.place(x=0, y=0)

test_cbb = ttk.Combobox(test_lbl, value=test_value)
test_cbb.configure(width=40)
test_cbb.place(x=5, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

I want to remove borderline of combobox,,

When I use tk.Entry, removed borderline through input "bd=0"....

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVhyU.png)